# Get content of .txt - file in a for-loop in batch

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, sqlplus

I'm using a batch file to search for certain files, `[0-9]_xxx.xyz`, and extract substrings from their paths. I want to put these substrings in a table in my Oracle DB.

This is the part of my code which does the fore-metioned task:

```
FOR /F "tokens=7,8,9,* delims=\" %%a in ('dir /B /S /A:-D "*_xxx.xyz"') do (
    @echo insert into tab (a,b,c,d,e^) values ('0','%%a','%%c','%%~dpd%%a\%%b\%%c','Content xxx.txt'^); | sqlplus USER/PW@DB
)
```

My problem is to get the content of the `.txt` file, *(always one line)*, in the loop and put it in row `e` in my `test_tab`. The `.txt` file is located at `%%~dpd%%a\%%b\%%c\xxx.txt`, and there is always just one `.txt` file per directory, where the `[0-9]_xxx.xyz` is located too.

Directory structure:

```
C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Input\object_group\1001_object\1001_module_name\1001_module.BAT_TEMPLATE
C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Input\object_group\1001_object\1001_module_name\1001_module.txt
```

If the first file exists, I need to write its data into the db. I need the single line content of the `.txt` file in a field of my table in the db.

A line in my db table has to look like this:

```
0 || object_group || 1001_object || source (whole path c:\...\\1001_module_name || first line of txt
```

`1001` is just an example, it's incremented for each module.

Is there a way to get the `.txt` content into a variable and get it into the database?

Comment: please copy the real code; the current ones contains superfluous line-breaks and can therefore not work. Anyway, I think you have to escape the closing `)` in the echoed text with `^)`; otherwise, they end the block that is began by `for … do (`…

Comment: Thank you! I've just echoed out the variables to see if I get what I need and didn't run the whole command. Now the command works - except the line of text in the .txt-file has still to be filled in.

Comment: In addition to the issues mentioned by aschipfl, you also have a missing closing doublequote on your `findstr` command too. Looking at your `dir` command, I would assume that `Dir /B /S /A:-D "*_xxx.xyz"` will be better that running every single file through the `findstr` pipe. Also you could probably improve your `findstr` match too `findstr.exe /I /R "[0123456789]_xxx\.xyz$"` would match those ending with a single integer, followed by `_xxx.xyz`. Although this might be improved, had you told us what your intended file pattern was.

Comment: My bad - missing doublequote was a typo. Followed your advice and edited my code. Thank you!

Comment: Your code is still invalid @PhilGee, please follow the advice of the last line in the first comment. Also, was there a specific reason why you did not clarify the filename pattern to match, in order that a more robust `Dir` and `FindStr` command combination could be used? It would also assist us were you to show us the tree structure, so that we could understand where tokens `7`, `8`, and `9` are being taken from.

Comment: Thanks for commenting @Compo! I guess I already did this by putting ```^)``` instead of ```)``` in the echoed text, or did I get it wrong? Furthermore, I edited my original post to provide more infoermation just as mentioned by you.

Comment: Did you read my comment @PhilGee? or the last line of the first one? Please copy exactly what you have posted in your question, paste it as a new batch file and run it. When you find that it doesn't work, which it will not, perhaps you will fix it to match the shown syntax `for … do (` which you can clearly see, has the opening parenthesis on the same line as the `do`. You have what may be deemed a superfluous line-break!

Comment: Wow... I guess I'm a little slow of the mark today ;-) But I guess now I got it... finally. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably try to write this in PowerShell, but if you're determined to use batch script, this should get you going:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%f in (`dir /s /b /a:-d *_xxx.xyz`) do (
    set filename=%%f
    echo !filename!
    echo.
    set break=
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%l in ("!filename!") do if not defined break (
        set line=%%l
        set break=yes
    )
    for /f "usebackq tokens=7,8,9,* delims=\" %%a in ('!filename!') do (
        set "sql=insert into tab (a,b,c,d,e^) values ('0','%%a','%%c','%%~dpd%%a\%%b\%%c','!line!'^);"
        echo !sql!
    )
)
```

Here, `for /f "usebackq delims=" %%l in ("!filename!")` reads the file line-wise. The combination of `usebackq` and double quotes around the `!filename!` ensure that paths with spaces don't cause errors.

`do if not defined break` stops the loop after the first iteration, i.e. it reads only one line. Since you said your files only contain one line anyway, it's more of a precaution.

The third loop then splits the path into various components, that's the loop you already had.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll give it a try :-)

Comment: Oh and by the way: Would you be so kind to point out why something like ```set /p text= <1001_module.txt``` in the loop and putting !text! in the SQLPlus Command does not work?

Comment: !line! gives me "´╗┐" in the output, which is caused by the encoding I guess. How is it possible to skip these chars?

Comment: @PhilGee You're getting closer and closer to PowerShell territory. Batch script is a terrible way to solve complex tasks like this.

Comment: I guess you've got a point there @Tomalak. It's really terrible - no doubt about it...

Comment: If I write it in the db or file, it looks fine, so I guess my problem is solved :-) Tank you so much!